# Выбор, откуда брать функцию (С++)

Tags: c++, функции, gcc, g++, кроссплатформенность

У меня имеется довольно странный вопрос.
Мне нужно использовать в проекте на С++ функцию `_getch`. Есть специально выделенные заголовок и файл с, собственно, кодом для платформозависимых функций (сделано все это через `#ifdef WINDOWS ... #endif #ifdef LINUX ... #endif`). Проблема заключается в том, что, в случае Windows, функция уже объявлена в заголовке `conio.h`, а в Linux/Unix ее нужно реализовать самостоятельно. Желательно, чтобы можно было просто подключить заголовок с платформозависимыми функциями и использовать `_getch`, дабы не исправлять каждый вызов. Возможно ли это сделать, и, если да, то как?
P.S. В качестве компилятора используется G++.
P.P.S. В принципе, можно просто сделать функцию, вызывающую, в случае Windows, `_getch` из себя, но меня интересует именно возможность использования функции с названием `_getch`, дабы не путаться.

Comment: Непонятны ваши проблемы. Почему нельзя использовать те же самые директивы препроцессора при определении функции или ее объявлении. В чем проблема-то?

Comment: #ifdef WIN
#include <conio.h>
#else
#include <some.h> - что-то типа такого

Comment: Приведите место "специально выделенного заголовка" где все это присходит, а то на словах не понятно

Answer (score 1):

Создаём заголовок: `MyCoolHeader.h`, в котором пишем:

```
#ifdef WINDOWS 
#include <conio.h>
#elif defined(LINUX )
inline ... _getch()
{
   ...
   Тут у нас реализация функции
}
#endif
```

Если реализация `_getch` получается длинной(>10 строк) лучше убрать `inline` и поместить реализацию в отдельный cpp файл, а в .h оставить лишь декларацию(так вообще лучше при любом раскладе).

Затем подключаете Ваш `MyCoolHeader.h` там где Вам нужно и используете `_getch()`

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к ответу @ixSci

Отдельный .cpp (или .c) файл с реализацией `_getch()` может быть очень простым

```
// my_getch.cpp
#ifndef WINDOWS
  // тут реализация 
#endif
```

Т.е. результат компиляции (файл my_getch.o) в windows  будет пустым, а в Linux будет содержать код `_getch()`. Такой подход не требует каких-либо ухищрений при написании Makefile.

Кстати, аналогичным образом  можно подменять любые стандартные библиотечные функции (допустим, printf).